# Finding relative orientation in Android

Tags: android, opencv, rotation, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I'm building an AR application where there is an object on the camera preview being tracked by a computer vision algorithm ([solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)). I want to make this experience smoother and use the phone's gyroscope to rotate the object in between solvePnP results. The first step to do this was to run solvePnP once, project the points on the screen and then rely on orientation *only* to track the object (I make sure not to translate the phone too much).

The desired effect is that, if I hold the phone on portrait mode, upright, with the camera pointing to some object of interest. If I rotate the phone positively about its vertical axis, I expect to see the corresponding object on the screen to rotate negatively about its vertical axis. I'm using [Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) to get the quaternions from the phone.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {

        if (!didInitRotation) {

           SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mInitialRotationMatrix, event.values);

            didInitRotation = true;
        }

        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, event.values);

        float[] rotationMatrixInverse = new float[16];
        float[] relativeOrientation = new float[16];

        Matrix.invertM(rotationMatrixInverse, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(relativeOrientation, 0, rotationMatrixInverse, 0, mInitialRotationMatrix, 0);

        mGLAssetSurfaceView.getRenderer().setRotationMatrix(relativeOrientation);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I hold a reference to some "initial rotation matrix" and then multiply it by the inverse of the current rotation matrix to get the relative orienation. I then apply this to the view matrix in OpenGL.

The result is that the `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` behaves strangely. If I rotate the phone about its x-axis, I see the object on the screen moving diagonally from one corner of the screen to another.